# Can't seem to get the position correct

Tags: html, css

So I just want to say sorry for messy code, I have tried vigorously with this. Basically I want there to be 3 images side by side which I will later make clickable, and a gray background behind them. Then I want to be able to include text below the images. Any help?

HTML

### Premium Store

```
   <table id="table1" >
   <tr id="imgs">
    <div id="tablet">
   <table border="0";>
      <td><img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/visualpharm/icons8-metro-style/128/Business-Assistant-icon.png"/></td>
   <td><img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/visualpharm/icons8-metro-style/128/Business-Delivery-icon.png"/></td>
   <td><img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/visualpharm/<icons8-metro->            </icons8-metro->style/128/Business-Shop-icon.png"/></td>
        </div>
   </tr>
   <td> 
         Contact a representative!
   </td>
   <td>
       Deliver to your house!
   </td>
   <td>
       Locate a store!
   </td>

    </table>
```

CSS

```
#backgroundH
{
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #dddddd;
  position: absolute;
}

#header
{
  top: -50px;
  color: black;   
  font-family: "Courier New";
  text-align: center;
}

body
{
  background-color: #cccccc;
}

#table1
{
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #d9d9d9;
  position: fixed;
  margin-left: -250px;
  margin-top: -100px;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
}

td
{
  width: 10px;
  height: 450px;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: -5px;
  margin-top: -225px;
  top: 35%;
  left: 3%;
}
```

Also please include what I did wrong! I am having a hard time understanding positioning, in-specific how to add a neat setup. (If somebody could skype with me I have some questions.. :P skype-ikorey1)

Thank you all for the help and reading. I really do appreciate all the feedback.

Comment: please use a [JSFidle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to make us help you better

Comment: @vishnu http://jsfiddle.net/tVy8q/

Comment: Please don't take this the wrong way, but I highly suggest you check out some of the intro courses for developing HTML/CSS -- it'll make your life a lot easier if you understand the fundamentals of what you're doing and best practices. There are great ones on [codeacademy](http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/web) or even paid courses on [treehouse](https://teamtreehouse.com)

Comment: I did the Codeacademy course, and I mean I need a solid video specifically on this subject on positioning. If you could link me one that would be fantastic.

Comment: Use <tr> as child of <table> and then <td> child of <tr> instead of directly under <table>. Remove ; in <table border="0";>

Answer (score 0):

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
      <style type="text/css">
    .img-with-text { float: left; text-align: center}
    </style>
  </head>


  <body>    
    <div class="container">
    <div class="img-with-text"><img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/visualpharm/icons8-metro-style/128/Business-Assistant-icon.png" border="0" alt=""   width="200" height="230" style="border: 2px solid black;" />
    <p>Anup<br />9096969903<br /><a href="mailto:anup08@boun.cr">Email Carl Call</a>  </p>
    </div>
    <div class="img-with-text"><img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/visualpharm/icons8-metro-style/128/Business-Delivery-icon.png" border="0" alt="" width="200" height="230" style="border: 2px solid black;" />
    <p>Anup<br />9096969903<br /><a href="mailto:anup08@boun.cr">Email Sjon Gentry</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="img-with-text"><img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/visualpharm/icons8-metro-style/128/Business-Assistant-icon.png" border="0" alt="" width="200" height="230" style="border: 2px solid black;" />
    <p>Anup<br />9096969903<br /><a href="mailto:anup08@boun.cr">Email John Mabery</a> </p>
    </div>    
    </div>

<!-- End of your code -->
    <p style="clear: both">Something more here </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a special way of making that type of arrangement (image with caption).
And this would be my way of doing what you need:

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <figure>
       <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/visualpharm/icons8-metro-style/128/Business-Assistant-icon.png"/>
      <figcaption>Fig.1 - A view of the pulpit rock in Norway.</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure>
      <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/visualpharm/icons8-metro-style/128/Business-Delivery-icon.png"/>
      <figcaption>Fig.1 - A view of the pulpit rock in Norway.</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure>
      <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/visualpharm/<icons8-metro->            </icons8-metro->style/128/Business-Shop-icon.png"/>
      <figcaption>Fig.1 - A view of the pulpit rock in Norway.</figcaption>
    </figure>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#container{
   background:#ccc;
}

#container figure{
   float:left
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this..

```
    <table id="table1">
    <tr id="imgs">
        <td>
            <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/visualpharm/icons8-metro-style/128/Business-Assistant-icon.png" />
            <p class="content">
                Contact a representative!
            </p>
        </td>

        <td>
            <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/visualpharm/icons8-metro-style/128/Business-Delivery-icon.png" />
            <p class="content">
                Deliver to your house!
            </p>
        </td>

        <td>
            <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/visualpharm/icons8-metro-style/128/Business-Shop-icon.png" />
            <p class="content">
                Locate a store!
            </p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and css

```
body {
        background-color: #cccccc;
    }

    #table1 {
        width: 500px;
        height: 200px;
        background-color: #d9d9d9;
        position: fixed;
        margin-left: -250px;
        margin-top: -100px;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
    }

    tr {
        width: 10px;
        height: 450px;
        position: relative;
        margin-left: -5px;
        margin-top: -225px;
        top: 35%;
        left: 3%;
    }

    td.content {
        position: absolute;
    }
```

and for position details are explained clearly in [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp)

which will helps us alot.